# $\int_{+\gamma} \bar{z} dz$ and $\int_{+\gamma} z dz$, where the contour is $z(\theta)=2e^{i\theta}$, $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I thought these two integrals are equal to zero, but after calculation, the first equals to $8\pi i$ and the second is equal to $2(e^{4\pi i}-1)$. Why is that? Are they, $\bar{z}$ and $z$, not continuous on $\mathbb C$ with some antiderivatives?

Comment: How did you calculate? Did you use Residue theorem or riemann sum or parametrization? i got 0 for both

Comment: @SakethMalyala I used the formula $\int_{+\gamma} f(z)dz = \int_0^{2\pi} f(z)z'(\theta)d\theta$. Mark's answer says the integral for $\bar{z}$ is not zero.

Comment: Your calculation was right, the integral for $\bar z$ is $8\pi i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $\int_\gamma zdz=0$. Note that $e^{4\pi i}=1$, so use that in your answer. As for the other integral it is really not zero. And why should it be? The function $f(z)=\bar z$ is not holomorphic (actually it isn't differentiable at any point) so you can't use Cauchy's theorem here. It also doesn't have an antiderivative.

Comment: Could you explain why does $f(z)=\bar{z} = x - iy$ not have an antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}$? I thought it has

Comment: Well, for example because if it had then your integral would be zero. But it isn't. Another explanation is that if it had an antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}$ then it would be a holomorphic function. (because its antiderivative would be holomorphic, and in complex analysis there is a theorem that states a holomorphic function is actually differentiable infinitely many times)

Answer (score 2):

The other answer has already addressed the fact that your second integral is, in fact, zero. Another way to tackle the first integral is to recognize that along your given contour,

$$z \overline{z} = 2^2 \implies \overline{z} = \frac 4 z.$$

Therefore, your first integral is just

$$8\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} 1 \cdot \frac{dz}{z - 0} = 8\pi i$$

by applying the Cauchy integral formula to the constant function $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{\gamma}zdz=0$ by Cauchy's theorem. You can also use the evident parameterization $z=2e^{i\theta}$. Then, calculate

$\int^{2\pi}_0(e^{i\theta})(2i\cdot2e^{i\theta})d\theta=4i\int^{2\pi}_0e^{i\theta}d\theta=0.$

Using the same parameterization (here Cauchy's theorem does not apply), you get

$\int_{\gamma }\overline z dz=\int^{2\pi}_0(e^{-i\theta})(2i\cdot2e^{i\theta})d\theta=4i\int^{2\pi}_0d\theta=8\pi i.$